# Is there a way to get autocomplete in a ui element in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to have a Listbox or similar, where the user could start typing, and the Listbox would narrow down the choices depending on what has already been typed, and autocomplete once a unique option had been reached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2011/05/autocomplete-email-addresses-in-apps.html for an example of autocomplete

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly easy in HtmlService and a bit harder in UiApp although doable. Here's an HtmlService example:

**Code File**

```
function getGroup(group) {
  return GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(group).getUsers().map(
    function(user){return user.getEmail(); });
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ui");
}
```

**Html file named 'ui'**

```
<html>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function refresh() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(tags) {$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: tags});})
        .getGroup(document.getElementById('group').value);
    }
  </script>

  Enter a group name in the first box. The second box will autocomplete
  group members using GroupApp.
  <br>
  <label for="group">Group: </label>
  <input id="group" onchange='refresh()'>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Members: </label>
    <input id="tags">
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @CoreyG any idea why your code doesn't work for me - using Chrome on Linux? -- I was so happy when found this post

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] HtmlService is faster and more advanced. UiApp works, but is slow because of the network.

The **HtmlService** solution here [Populate jQuery autocomplete list using value array from Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923402/populate-jquery-autocomplete-list-using-value-array-from-google-spreadsheet/17928216#17928216) is much better.

A **UiApp** version:  https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/uiapp-examples-code-snippets/suggest-box

Or this way that I built:

To see it in action, type an airport name into:
http://www.treesforlife.org.au/carbon-calculator

But this was is done with spreadsheet formulas, not google-apps-script. see http://www.cellmaster.com.au

Comment: broken link..https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/apps-script/BzvEGbMeSt0/discussion

Comment: (edit) removed broken link - added two new links to better solutions