# UiApp TextBox auto complete

Tags: google-apps-script

Got a question about the UiApp.

I have created a function that changes the cityList values when i type in the cityBox (this works)

But sometimes a autocomplete box of my browser shows up when i have already used that value. Is there a Handler function that detects if i click the autocomplete box?

this is a bit of my code:

```
  var cityPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setWidth(400);
  cityPanel.add(app.createLabel("Plaats:"))
  var cityHandler = app.createServerHandler("getCity").addCallbackElement(cityPanel);
  var cityBox = app.createTextBox().setWidth(300).setName("cityBox").addKeyUpHandler(cityHandler);
  var cityList = app.createListBox().setVisibleItemCount(5).setWidth(300).setId("cityList").setName("cityList");
  cityPanel.add(cityBox)
    .add(cityList);
```

With kind regards,

Thomas van Latum

Comment: addBlurHandler - detects a focus change. - maybe it would work. Can you explain what will happen after they click the auto complete.

Comment: Sure thing the text you klick on will be put in the textbox but the focus wont change.

Comment: If you are talking about "browser" style auto complete, rather than javascript style. Then there is probably no way to detect it. But I suspect you mean JavaScript style, if so, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416594/is-there-a-way-to-get-autocomplete-in-a-ui-element-in-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no feature in a UiApp text box that can detect or prevent the browser-level auto-complete box.